# Android AVD Emulator Runaway CPU. Fix? Anyone else having the same problem?

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio

When run one Emulator the CPU runs real hard, about 4 X times as before an upgrade a couple of weeks ago. Seems like each Emulator is using more RAM than before as well. Can only run at most 3 Emulator  before the computer becomes overloaded and unresponsive, before could run at least 8.

I checked to make sure all the required Linux libraries are on the machine.

Filed a bug on Android Studio as:
Issue 173578:   Race condition when running AVD Emulator since updating Android SDK Tools, revision 24.2

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=173578&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=173578

Just started UI tuning (Again) and this problem is killing me time wise since I can not open many emulators to check the UI.

Anyone else having the same or similar problem? If so star the bug report.

Anyone know of a fix?